# Issue running Python unittests: "Empty suite" error

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-3.9

I've created the function and trying to test it, but when I ran the test I got the "Empty suite" error. Why?

That's the module I imported in the file where I've gotten the issue.

```
def get_formatted_name(fname, lname):
    """Get neatly formatted full name."""
    fullna = fname + ' ' + lname
    return fullna.title()
```

That's the unit test.

```
import unittest
from names_function import get_formatted_name


class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'name_fucntion.py'."""

    def test_fname_lname(self):
        """Do names like 'Volodymyr Zelenskyy' work?"""
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('volodymyr', 'zelenskyy')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Volodymyr Zelenskyy')


if __name__ == '__main__':  # <-- that's why got the issue. I haven't write it.
    unittest.main()  # tells Python to run the tests in this file.
```

Comment: How are you running the test?